# Specifiying twice LWA_COLORKEY in Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to find a way to be able to replace 2 COLORS on a specific Window (which isn't made by me, it's another problem).

```
LONG ExtendedStyle = GetWindowLong(handle,GWL_EXSTYLE );
SetWindowLong(handle,GWL_EXSTYLE,ExtendedStyle | WS_EX_LAYERED );
::SetLayeredWindowAttributes(handle,RGB(251,254,249),0,LWA_COLORKEY);
```

This works well, now I'm trying to call twice:

```
::SetLayeredWindowAttributes(handle,RGB(251,254,249),0,LWA_COLORKEY);
```

with a different color code

```
LONG ExtendedStyle = GetWindowLong(handle,GWL_EXSTYLE );
SetWindowLong(handle,GWL_EXSTYLE,ExtendedStyle | WS_EX_LAYERED );
::SetLayeredWindowAttributes(handle,RGB(251,254,249),0,LWA_COLORKEY);
::SetLayeredWindowAttributes(handle,RGB(251,254,220),0,LWA_COLORKEY);
```

This does NOT work and only the last one is taken into account, I've searched extensively and wish to not go into too advanced solutions as my problem seems simple. Anyone has a clue?

EDIT: I'm sorry I'm very unfamiliar with this API and I have a client that requires me to replace 2 colors (or more) in a window, I'm already losing way too much time on this. Your help is very very welcome. Thank you

Comment: If you control the window in question, you would need to use per-pixel alpha transparency instead of color key transparency. If you do not control the window, then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` only supports 1 transparent color at a time. For more advanced transparency/translucency needs, you have to use `UpdateLayeredWindow()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've started looking into UpdateLayeredWindow but I don't see how I can do 2 colors at the same time, it seems that I can do one, then one, then one (which erase the previous one).

I need to replace 2 colors by 2 other colors in a Window which I do not control.

Answer (score 2):

According to the document of [**SetLayeredWindowAttributes function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes), if you use a parameter LWA_COLORKEY, all areas of the form where the color is crKey will become transparent and the bAlpha parameter is invalid. So only the last function is valid. If you want to make multiple areas transparent, you can set them to the same color in advance.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the area in the Window, I need to replace a certain set of colors (example #FFF and #000) by other ones, but multiple ones, not just one.

Comment: Like @Remy Lebeau said, try UpdateLayeredWindow() to make multiple areas transparent.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not really looking to make an area transparent, I'm looking to replace 2 colors by 2 other colors. I've checked the doc of UpdateLayeredWindow() and I'm not seeing information that would allow me to do that without having to constantly call it.

Comment: You can draw a Rectangle the size of the client area in the WM_PAINT message, use Rectangle and set the fill color to cover the background color.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it does cover the background of the initial window (the color in the original window is still there, the rectangle is simply on top), it doesn't replace a pixel by another one :/

Comment: Your question is that you want to make multiple color areas transparent. Now you want to replace two colors with two colors. Is this relevant? Or can I take a look at your interface?

Comment: Actually I have not posted that it's to make the areas transparent, transparent is just one of the colors possible, the real goal is to replace X colors by X colors, without knowing ahead where they are